# Print all cycles of the graph for the specified node of the graph, Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory, cycle

I'm newbie in the Prolog world. I'm trying to write predicate for printing all cycles of the graph for the specified node of the graph, which is the element of the given node. My graph looks like this.

```
edge(a,e).
edge(e,d).
edge(d,c).
edge(c,b).
edge(b,a).
edge(d,a).
edge(e,c).
edge(f,b).

cycle(X) :-
    cycle(X, []).

cycle(Curr, Visited) :-
    member(Curr, Visited),
    !.
cycle(Curr, Visited) :-
    edge(Curr, Next),
    cycle(Next, [Curr|Visited]).
```

Unfortunately now I cannot find cycle for specific node. For example I'm looking for all cycles for node `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you simply **do not have any logic written to return the cycle**.

## Cycles that originate from a node

This is not that hard, you already use an accumulator, you simply need a mechanism that once the cycle is found, return your accumulator as cycle. You can do this by providing an additional parameter to `cycle`:

```
cycle(Node,Cycle) :-
    cycle(Node,[],Cycle).

cycle(Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    member(Curr,Visited),
    !,
    reverse([Curr|Visited],Cycle).
cycle(Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    edge(Curr,Next),
    cycle(Next,[Curr|Visited],Cycle).
```

In this implementation I used `reverse/2` since this will give you the correct order of the nodes (edge-wise). If you are not interested in this (for instance you only wish to analyze the cycle, and you can analyze this the opposite way, you can simply substitute `Cycle` in the first clause of `cycle/3` with `[Curr|Visited]`.

The problem is however that if you call this predicate, it returns:

```
?- cycle(d,Cycle).
Cycle = [d, c, b, a, e, d] ;
Cycle = [d, c, b, a, e, c] ;
Cycle = [d, a, e, d] ;
Cycle = [d, a, e, c, b, a].
```

It thus not searches for cycles **where `d` is part of the cycle** per se, it searches for all cycles that can **originate from `d`**. This is probably not what you want.

## Cycles with a given node

You can however rewrite the predicate: you will need to store the node from which you originate:

```
cycle(Node,Cycle) :-
    edge(Node,Next),
    cycle(Node,Next,[Node],Cycle).
```

So here we look for every `edge/2` originating from `Node` and we call `cycle/4` with the initial `Node` (to check when we have found a cycle), the `Next` node, the list of visited `[Node]`s and the `Cycle` parameter to return found cycles.

Now there are three possible options for `cycle/4`:

- We arrive at the original node, in that case we have found a cycle where `Node` is part from, we do processing similar to the first version:

  ```
  cycle(Curr,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
      !,
      reverse([Curr|Visited],Cycle).
  ```
- We arrive in a node we already visited: `Curr` is an element of `Visited`, in that case we need to break off search: otherwise we will cycle for an infinite amount of times:

  ```
  cycle(_,Curr,Visited,_) :-
      member(Curr,Visited),
      !,
      fail.
  ```

  `fail` is a predicate that states the branch fails. This can be useful, because now we specify how it can fail.
- Finally we simply visited another edge and try to find the next node:

  ```
  cycle(Node,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
      edge(Curr,Next),
      cycle(Node,Next,[Curr|Visited],Cycle).
  ```

The full version is:

```
cycle(Node,Cycle) :-
    edge(Node,Next),
    cycle(Node,Next,[Node],Cycle).

cycle(Curr,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    !,
    reverse([Curr|Visited],Cycle).
cycle(_,Curr,Visited,_) :-
    member(Curr,Visited),
    !,
    fail.
cycle(Node,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    edge(Curr,Next),
    cycle(Node,Next,[Curr|Visited],Cycle).
```

Which generates:

```
?- cycle(d,Cycle).
Cycle = [d, c, b, a, e, d] ;
Cycle = [d, a, e, d] ;
```

All are thus cycles starting from `d` and visiting `d` again. We can make the code a bit more efficient by compressing the second and third scenario in one clause:

```
cycle(Node,Cycle) :-
    edge(Node,Next),
    cycle(Node,Next,[Node],Cycle).

cycle(Curr,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    !,
    reverse([Curr|Visited],Cycle).
cycle(Node,Curr,Visited,Cycle) :-
    \+ member(Curr,Visited),
    edge(Curr,Next),
    cycle(Node,Next,[Curr|Visited],Cycle).
```

Where `\+` means *not*.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I really appriciate your answer it helped me a lot. Now I completely get it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for sounds like [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) to me... no need to reinvent the wheel!

Simply build upon tried-and-tested code shown in "[Definition of a path/trail/walk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/4609915)" and define:

```
in_cycle(R_2, AZ, Path) :-                  % cf. "simple cycle"
   First = AZ,
   Last  = AZ,
   path(R_2, Path, First, ButLast),         % all "hops" but the last one ...
   call(R_2, ButLast, Last).                % ... and here comes the last one
```

Sample query #1 using [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/) 4.3.2:

```
| ?- in_cycle(edge, d, Path).
Path = [d,c,b,a,e] ? ;
Path = [d,a,e] ? ;
no
```

In sample query #2, we look at the transitive closure of the [symmetric closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_closure) of `edge/2`:

```
| ?- in_cycle(symm(edge), d, Path).
Path = [d,c] ? ;
Path = [d,c,b,a] ? ;
Path = [d,c,b,a,e] ? ;
Path = [d,c,e] ? ;
Path = [d,c,e,a] ? ;
Path = [d,a] ? ;
Path = [d,a,e] ? ;
Path = [d,a,e,c] ? ;
Path = [d,a,b,c] ? ;
Path = [d,a,b,c,e] ? ;
Path = [d,e] ? ;
Path = [d,e,c] ? ;
Path = [d,e,c,b,a] ? ;
Path = [d,e,a] ? ;
Path = [d,e,a,b,c] ? ;
no
```

All solutions of query #1 *also* fulfill the more general query #2—monotonic Prolog<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31941407/4609915),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15709808/4609915),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33184471/4609915)</sup> at work:)